# How to linearize a nonlinear ODE around its equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-writing, dynamical-systems, self-learning

I am studying for a comprehensive exam in non-linear ODE's and I have this in my book:
$$\ddot{\xi}+c\bigg[x_1+\xi-\dfrac{\lambda}{a-x_1-\xi}\bigg] = 0$$ then it goes straight to

$$\ddot{\xi}+c\bigg[1-\dfrac{\lambda}{(a-x_1)^2}\bigg]\xi = 0.$$

How do they obtain this?

Thank you for any help or comments!

$\bf{ADD}:$ The original differential equation is 
$$\ddot{x}+c\bigg[x-\dfrac{\lambda}{a-x}\bigg] = 0$$ and $x = x_1+\xi$, where $x_1$ is a constant.

Comment: Are there any special conditions on $\xi$?

Comment: You obtain $2^{nd}$ ODE by expanding the original ODE as a power series of $\xi$ and then throw away quadratic and other higher order terms in the expansion. If I remember correctly, this is called linearization of non-linear ODE. people do this to study the stability of the solution of non-linear systems.

Comment: What is the independent variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll describe the situation in more general terms, since you won't have the same equation on your exam. Write the original ODE as $$\ddot{x}+F(x)=0$$ This ODE may have an *equilibrium solution* $x\equiv x_1$, provided that the equation $F(x_1)=0$ has a solution. (In your example, it does.)  We linearize the ODE around this equilibrium (as achille hui said) by letting $x=x_1+\xi$, so that $\xi$ is "small", and the approximation $F(x_1+\xi)\approx  F'(x_1)\xi$ is reasonable. This leads to the *linear* ODE 
$$ \ddot{\xi } +F'(x_1)\xi =0$$
In your example $F(x)=  c\bigg[x-\dfrac{\lambda}{a-x}\bigg]$, thus $F'(x_1)=c\bigg[1-\dfrac{\lambda}{(a-x_1)^2}\bigg]$.